# Is there not a way to completely delete an object from the scene?

Tags: mesh, texturing, objects

I don't know if this is just an issue for me but deleting a rig along with all its hierarchy including bones and mats in object mode doesn't fully delete them for me. The object disappears from the outliner, but if I switch to Blender File mode, images and materials still remain, resulting in a bigger .blend file if I decide to import another object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either:

- save the file, close and reopen it: every unused and unprotected datablock will be removed.
- go to the outliner, set its mode to "Orphan data", click the "Purge" button, click it again until it will stop acting, as it works on hierarchies with one by one steps. If some items are unassigned and protected they will show a shield icon (fake user), you can choose if to remove the protection and delete them or leave the shield and mantain them in the file.

[image]

Comment: For the repeated purging to step through the hierarchy, there are also _Recursive..._ cleaning options in the _File_ > _Clean Up_ menu which will do the repeated purging for you.

Answer (score 2):

If the material is no longer used, it will still appear in the *Outliner*, with the prefix 0, but if you close and reopen the file, it won't be available anymore, Blender has got rid of it (that's what happens to the data preeceded by a 0). The image that your material use will still be here because it is one level below in the hierarchy, but this time it has the 0 prefix and if you close and reopen again the file, this time the image will be deleted. This is how the things are done in Blender (yes a bit complicated).

But to quickly get rid of all the unused datas you can go into the *Orphan Data* list of the *Outliner* and click on the *Purge* button, of *File > Clean-Up > Unused Data-Blocks*.

As pointed out by Gordon, *there is also *Recursive Unused Data-Blocks* option also including any indirectly used data-blocks i.e. those only used by unused data-blocks*.

Comment: Like commented above, there is also _Recursive Unused Data-Blocks_ option also including any indirectly used data-blocks i.e. those only used by unused data-blocks.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Oh ok thanks I've forgotten this one